# Is my proof correct? (Lebesgue integrable functions)

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\Omega,\mathcal{A}, \mu).$ Prove that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a bounded $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function $g$ such that $\int_{\Omega} |f-g| d\mu < \epsilon$.

My proof:

$$f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\Omega,\mathcal{A}, \mu) $$
$$\Rightarrow \int_{\Omega} |f| d\mu < \infty$$
$$\Rightarrow |f| \text{ is finite } \mu-ae$$
$$\Rightarrow \text{ Let } D = \{x: f(x) < \infty\}, \text{ then } \mu(D^c) = 0$$

Let $$g(x) = \begin{cases}
   f(x) & \text{if } x \in D \\
   0       & \text{otherwise } 
  \end{cases}$$
then $g(x)$ is bounded and $\int_{\Omega} |f-g| d\mu =  \int_D |f-g| d\mu = 0 < \epsilon$.

But this is a stronger result than stated as $g$ does not depend on $\epsilon$!

Comment: $g$ is not necessarily bounded, just finite everywhere. Boundedness means $|g(x)| \leq C$ for **all** $x$, where $C$ does **not** depend on $x$!

Comment: I agree on the definition but how can a function be unbounded but finite? Can you give an example?

Comment: $g(x) = x$ is an example

Comment: Or $g( x)= 1/\sqrt {x} \cdot 1_{(0,1)}(x)$. This is an example of an unbounded, everywhere finite, integrable function.

Comment: Does anybody haven an idea how to prove this question?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the function $f$ is not necessarily bounded on $D$ (that is, by a uniform constant), as the choice $g( x)= 1/\sqrt {x} \cdot 1_{(0,1)}(x)$.

However, we can define $E_n:=\{x\mid|f(x)|\lt n\}$ and $f_n(x)$ equal to $f(x)$ if $x$ belongs to $E_n$ and $0$ otherwise. Using the monotone convergence theorem, we can show that $\int_{\Omega}|f-f_n|\mathrm d\mu$ converges to $0$. Since each $f_n$ is bounded, we are done after a good choice of $n$ when $\varepsilon$ is given.